# Why am i getting this "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException"?

Tags: java

```
String s = e.nextLine();
String[] sa = s.split("+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sa));
```

My input is "1+2+3" . The regex: "+" giving dangling metacharacter error.
what is it?

Comment: Please do not link to graphics. Paste the text into the question and format it, usually with the "{}" tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character `+` in regex is a reserved character (it means "at least one occurrence of the character written previously")
To solve your issue, you need to escape it with double back slash: `"\\+"`

Comment: Have you changed your code to `String[] sa = s.split("\\+");` ?

Comment: yes.
String s = e.nextLine();
String[] sa = s.split("\\+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sa));

Comment: So the "\\+" solved the issue object of this post. This is another issue related to other parts of your code,which seems to use Scanner. Please write another post with further details

Comment: but this is the same problem .